# Accessing virtual LAMP server from my browser?

Tags: virtual-machine, lamp

I set up a LAMP server on virtual machine using VirtualBox. I want to be able to access that virtual server from my browser on the same box that the virtual server is running on. Many of the suggestions I've found don't seem to be working. I've already changed the conf file to Listen on port 8080, and have tried accessing localhost:8080 from my browser. I've also given my virtual server a static IP address of 172.19.0.10 and tried to access it by pointing my browser to 172.19.0.10:8080. I feel like I'm missing something key and I'm not sure what. Any help? The OS is Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit Server edition.

Comment: Sounds like you're settings are right from that stand point, however, is your network mode in VBOX set-up as bridged?

Comment: Are the services properly started on the guest system? At the very least, is Apache running?

Comment: Also, check if some proxy (such as iptables) isn't blocking external connections. I had such issue once.

Comment: @ruda.almeida Brings up a good point, have you gone to `127.0.0.1` on your server to verify that apache is for sure running? If it's GUI-less you could do it in links with `links 127.0.0.1` (it should show "It Works!").

Comment: My network mode is set to NAT. I just tried changing it to bridged but when that's the case I can't access the internet from the server (I tried pinging google.com and tried lynx for google.com). I tried the command links 127.0.0.1 but am getting a 'Connection refused' message. I'm not sure how else to test if Apache is running, or how to check if a proxy is blocking external connections. Thanks for the help guys, I'm still very new to this.